# Pythonanywhere internal server errors MySQL connection not available

Tags: python, mysql, flask, pythonanywhere

I am hosting a Flask webapp on Python anywhere and I have bought their first package with 6 workers instead of 2. Around 50% of the time when my webapp tries to do something with my database I will get an 'Internal server error'.

The error log says the following:

```
raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) MySQL Connection not available.
```

And the server log says:

```
SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /projects (ip 10.0.0.66) !!!
```

My code to connect to the database is as follows:

./app.py

```
from Website import create_app

app = create_app()
```

./Website/__init__.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Something something'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+mysqlconnector://{username}:{password}@{hostname}/{databasename}".format(
    username="username",
    password="set_MySQL_password",
    hostname="provided_hostname",
    databasename="username$database",
)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

def create_app():
    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

    from .models import User, Project, Candidates, Vote, Ranking

    # Send the user back to the login page if an account is required
    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        return User.query.get(id)

    return app
```

It will do this even with the most basic things. The error doesn't suggest it is a timeout issue but it doesn't seem logical that there is an error that is only popping up half of the time. I am the only on the website at the moment. In the access log all response times seem to stay below 0.1 seconds easily.

Have I done something wrong? How can I fix this? I wouldn't like to buy anymore workers if 6 isn't enough for one person.

EDIT:
I think this has to do with me not closing my connections:
I use

```
db.session.add()
db.session.commit()
```

to add things to the database. Should I close the database every time I add something?
Something like `db.session.close()`?
Is there a way to close connections after the user leaves the website?

Comment: Maybe get in touch with Python Anywhere's support folks?

Comment: Are you able to connect with your db via PythonAnywhere Bash console using this command: `mysql -u USERNAME -h HOSTNAME -p 'USERNAME$DATABASENAME'` with the same credentials you're using in the web app?

Comment: @caseneuve yes I can do that

Comment: We have a help page about managing connections here: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/ManagingDatabaseConnections/